# New SDK Tool and APK size

Tags: android, sdk, apk

Yesterday I updated SDK Tool to version 22 and relative Eclipse ADT.

Today I export my project in APK file and I am surprise from file size.

Last APK version was 452 Kb (few days ago), new APK is 325 Kb (I change only few code rows to fix bugs). Does it depends on the new version that optimizes APK creation?

Comment: I figure that some of your resources got cut-out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the compression is better perhaps, but i'd do a good test.

You can unpack the .apk as if it was a .zip file and you can check the /res/ folder to see if all images are there, since that is probably most of the size. 
Also check if all jars are in, and that pages that should crash without them still work.

If yes, then it just seems they improved compression and you should be happy :)

Comment: I am happy :-) The only size difference is in file classes.dex so I think they improve compression